# Is it reasonably efficient to insert into an rvalue reference to a stream?

Tags: c++, c++11

I made a custom stream type, call it `error_stream`, which derives from `std::ostringstream`. I also made a custom manipulator for the stream called `throw_cpp_class` (`throw_cpp` is an instance of `throw_cpp_class`). My goal was to have this syntax:

```
error_stream s;
s << "some error " << message() << throw_cpp; // throw_cpp throws an exception containing contents of the stream.
```

I discovered that by defining an insertion operator which takes an rvalue reference to the stream as the first operand, I can now do this:

```
error_stream() << "some error " << message() << throw_cpp;
```

The insertion operator looks like this:

```
error_stream& operator<<(error_stream&& s, const throw_cpp_class&)
{
    throw s.str();
    return s;
}
```

What's going on here? Why can I return a value of type `error_stream&&` where an `error_stream&` is required? (Does this invoke the move constructor?). Is this horribly inefficient? (Not that I really care, given that the exception should be rare).

Comment: That's actually kind of neat...  I think I might prefer `throw_cpp<std::logic_error>` though, to throw that error with the contents of the stream.

Comment: I'd drop the return type and the `return os` statement. It's a semantic error to write `s << "some error " << message() << throw_cpp  << "more";`. By returning `void`, it also becomes a syntax error and the compiler will catch it.

Comment: @MSalters -- good point. I made the change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With this code:

```
error_stream& operator<<(error_stream&& s, const throw_cpp_class&)
{
    throw s.str();
    return s;
}
```

You can return `error_stream&& s` as a `error_stream&`, because `s` is an *lvalue*, and it is NOT an rvalue.

"What?" you ask?  "But I see `&&` right there!".  This part of C++ is tricky.  When you see `type&& s` (and `type` is not a template), then that means the variable is an rvalue reference, which is a reference that is "constructed from" an rvalue.  But it has a name: `s`.  And everything with a name is an lvalue.  That's *why* you have to call `std::move` sometimes, because you have to let the compiler know that you want it to treat that variable as an rvalue again.

> Does this invoke the move constructor?).

Nope, it simply returns a reference to the lvalue `s`.

> Is this horribly inefficient? (Not that I really care, given that the exception should be rare).

Nope, since there's no copy nor even a move happening.

---

Unrelated to your actual question, most overloads for streams are:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&& s, const T&)
```

then that means that unless `throw_cpp` is the *first thing streamed*, your overload won't be called, because the previous thing streamed will return an `ostream&`, not an `error_stream&&`.  (Note they *ought* to be templates, but many aren't, and it's irrelevant to the point) You'll have to cast it back to a `error_stream`.

Also, that's not how manipulators work.  Manipulators are *functions*, and when you stream those functions to a stream, the stream calls the function and passes *itself* as a parameter, so you'd want something more like so:

```
template <class exception, class charT, class traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>& throw_cpp(std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os)
{
    error_stream& self = dynamic_cast<error_stream&>(os); //maybe throws std::bad_cast
    throw exception(self.str());
    return os; //redundant, but the compiler might not know that.
}
```

[Here it is at work (with stringstream)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e2ab31fe9ca92ff70f292c8ff955f7b5-803889f054654ad4b92ce24ea171578e)

Comment: HA! Good point.  This was basically just a link to the other answer.  I removed that sentence now that this answer is actually _longer_ than the linked-to.

Answer (score 3):

`T&&` is an rvalue-reference, but its *value category* is that of a reference (an lvalue) so it can be stored inside an lvalue-reference. No move/copy constructors are called in this case either, because it is taken/returned by reference.

I wouldn't say this is inefficient in the least bit, but rather a common and idiomatic use of rvalue-references.